# Reading from Command Line in C

Tags: c, string, command-line, getline

I have a program (in C) that runs in the command line, and I am looking to have it accept strings of arbitrary length from users.  If I were programming in C++, I would probably use the getline() function in the string library, but I can't seem to find a C equivalent.  Do I just need to read characters in blocks of X length, and if the string goes over X length, make a new bigger block and copy data over to the new block?

Comment: There's a nonstandard [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) available for POSIX systems. Other than that, you can roll your own using `getc` and `realloc`.

Comment: not familiar with `getline()`, but instead of copying the string to progressively larger and larger blocks of memory, ideally you would only allocate blocks of X length as needed, while keeping track of each block allocated. this collection of 1 or more blocks would represent the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fgets` with `sscanf`.

Note that `getline` is now present in the current POSIX:2008 standard.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html

Comment: `fgets` needs a maximum length, and why not just use `scanf` in the first place?

Comment: @minitech `fgets` + `sscanf` is usually preferred over `scanf` see http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html for more information

Comment: Okay, but that really doesn't answer the question then. Edit: nevermind, saw edit.

Comment: So if I want to read from the command line instead of a file, what do I pass into the file parameter of get line()?

Comment: @mrswmmr you pass `stdin` which is a macro defined in `stdio.h`

Answer (score 0):

Use the readline library http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html (if you don't like the license there is also a BSD equivalent).

From there, you get to use the function `readline()`, which will return to you a `char *` of the line the user typed (make sure to call `free()` on it when you're done or you will have a memory leak).  There is even options you can set so that your users can press the up arrow to get their previous line (like in almost every other terminal).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `realloc()` to grow your input buffer.  There is no need to copy the data over; it does that for you.  A common pattern is:

```
if (n_read >= buf_size) {
  buf_size *= 2;
  *buf = realloc(sizeof(char) * buf_size);
}
```